# How get the text with BeautifulSoup in this html code: <span id="pass_0" class="text-success">c#</span>

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm doing a program that crack some hash, through `selenium` and `beautifulsoup` with this website: https://hashkiller.co.uk/Cracker

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

target = requests.get("https://hashkiller.co.uk/Cracker")
soup = BeautifulSoup(target.content, 'html.parser')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\Download\chromedriver.exe")
#driver.set_window_position(-10000,0)
#240aa2cec4b29c56f3bee520a8dcee7e
driver.get("https://hashkiller.co.uk/Cracker")
hash = input("Hash: ")
hash_box = driver.find_element_by_id("txtHashList").send_keys(hash)
hash_submit = driver.find_element_by_id("btnCrack").click()
time.sleep(5)
hash_table = soup.find('span', {'class': 'text-success'})
a = hash_table.text
print(hash_table)
```

i expect the output is `c#` [Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx03P.jpg ] Html Code: [`html <span id="pass_0" class="text-success">c#</span>`]

but it returns: `html<span class="text-success">$pass</span>`
instead of `$pass` there should be `c#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually not parsing the rendered html. You're parsing the html response from your `requests`.

Secondly, you want to grab the second element, as the first element is the `$pass`. Also, change `hash` to a different variable as it's a function in python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time




#target = requests.get("https://hashkiller.co.uk/Cracker")
#soup = BeautifulSoup(target.content, 'html.parser')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/chromedriver.exe")
#driver.set_window_position(-10000,0)
#240aa2cec4b29c56f3bee520a8dcee7e
driver.get("https://hashkiller.co.uk/Cracker")

hash_input = input("Hash: ")

hash_box = driver.find_element_by_id("txtHashList").send_keys(hash_input)

hash_submit = driver.find_element_by_id("btnCrack").click()
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

hash_table = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'text-success'})
a = hash_table[1].text
print(hash_table)
print(a)


driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
[<span class="text-success">$pass</span>, <span class="text-success" id="pass_0">c#</span>]
c#
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot chitown88 :)